# Example of Reading Data and Writing Directly Into Excel

Tags: c#, export-to-excel

I currently have a routine which reads rows/columns and writes into a SQL table from a `SELECT` statement.

We were thinking of then reading the SQL table and updating an empty Excel worksheet. What I would like to do is read and then update the data directly into Excel.

My program currently does the following:

1. Opening the workbook.
2. Accessing the different worksheets.
3. Saving As a new workbook name.
4. Closing Excel.

I just need an example that:

1. will allow the first row to be the column names
2. then read out the data into the various cells for each row.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/151005/create-excel-xls-and-xlsx-file-from-c-sharp

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/excellibrary/

Comment: I would strongly recommend NOT using the excel com-interop assemblies.  They will haunt you.

Comment: There are many tools to achieve what you want what was previously suggested by granadaCoder is one option, don't expect to get any code here unless you have shown your efforts towards your goal.

Comment: @granadaCoder unless you're writing an Add-in. Then you have no choice :(

Answer (score 0):

I do not recommend using COM Interop either.

You can find here a sample about [exporting dataset to Excel in C#](http://www.easyxls.com/manual/basics/export-dataset-to-excel.html).

It requires an Excel tool named [EasyXLS](http://www.easyxls.com).

Answer (score 0):

to open the file you can do it like that:

```
Dim exAppl As New Excel.Application    
exAppl.Visible = True
Dim exMappe As Excel.Workbook = exAppl.Workbooks.Open("C:\... .xlsx", , False)
```

You can acces to a Cell with

```
Console.WriteLine(exAppl.Range("A2").Value())
```

or when you whant to go throw it use something like that:

```
For i As Integer = 1 To exAppl.Rows.Count

    Dim a As Excel.Range = exAppl.Rows(i)

    For j As Integer = 1 To a.Columns.Count
        Dim b As Excel.Range = a.Columns(j)
        Console.WriteLine(b.Value)
    Next
Next
```

Comment: sorry that was vb.net, you can convert it easy using http://converter.telerik.com/